# How to work on a copy of a WordPress site

Tags: wordpress

Just landed my first freelance job where I have to edit a already build WordPress site. However before beginning, I was thinking that it might be better if I somehow could edit a copy of the original WordPress site? That way I can always go back to the original if the client should be unhappy with the changes. Does anyone know if this is possible?

Comment: Do you mean the content or the source code of the site?

Comment: I guess I mean the source code. My job is to add another language to the site, and buttons so that the user can switch between the languages. Already found a plugin (multi language switcher). However I don't want to add the plugin to the actual site right away.  I want to test it first

Answer (score 2):

Yes this is possible.

- copy all files
- copy the database
- edit wp-config.php (database credentials for development database)
- search and replace the live URL with development URL in all database tables ([good tool](https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/))
- maybe you have to adjust `.htaccess` rewirte rules to you development URL

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass these steps :

- moving your file form your machine to your webhost
- Export your database from your machine to your webhost
- edit wp-config.php to your new login and password for database
- Access to Database from phpmyadmin and edit this table `wp_options` and edit the two first rows change the url you have into the new url of your website
- acces to Backoffice and save the parmalinks again to regenerate .htaccess file or you can do it manually by editing first lines